# Quick OSM in Modeler - Line Filter

Tags: qgis, query, quickosm

I am using a working OSM Query module, mostly extracted from [HERE](https://github.com/3liz/QuickOSM/blob/master/QuickOSM/resources/model/osm_download_style.model3).  My only trouble is that I would like to filter some of the extracted data.

The raw query is a pretty open call for everything and then I believe the vector filter is done in the 'Convert format' module like this:

[image]

I would like to know, how I can add a filter so I only get tertiary, service and residential roads?

I do know if you use the filter code below in QuickOSM (not in the Raw Query in the Model Designer) it works fine to filter out the given line types, but it doesn't translate well into the Raw Query of the Model Designer)

````
```

         [out:xml] [timeout:25];
(
    node["area:highway"="unclassified"]["area:highway"="tertiary"]["area:highway"="service"]["area:highway"="residential"]["area:highway"]( {{bbox}});
    way["area:highway"="unclassified"]["area:highway"="tertiary"]["area:highway"="service"]["area:highway"="residential"]["area:highway"]( {{bbox}});
    relation["area:highway"="unclassified"]["area:highway"="tertiary"]["area:highway"="service"]["area:highway"="residential"]["area:highway"]( {{bbox}});
);
(._;>;);
out body;

```
````

[image]